# C# The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Math.Round(double, int)' and 'System.Math.Round(decimal, int)

Tags: c#, ambiguity

My code won't compile due to the error below:

The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Math.Round(double, int)' and 'System.Math.Round(decimal, int)

My code is

```
Math.Round(new FileInfo(strFilePath).Length / 1024, 1)
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The problem is that you make an integer division (results also in an `int`) and a `int` can be implicitly converted to both `double` and `decimal`. Therefore, you need to make sure the expression results in one of those; `double` is probably what you want.

```
Math.Round(new FileInfo(strFilePath).Length / 1024.0, 1)
```

Answer (score 53):

```
Math.Round(new FileInfo(strFilePath).Length / 1024d, 1)
```

Comment: This is way better than the accepted answer, you should not implicitly cast using ".0", using 'd' suffix is explicit and preferred.

Comment: Better yes, but the explanation in the accepted answer as to _why_ is extremely helpful.

Answer (score 14):

```
Math.Round((double) (new FileInfo(strFilePath).Length / 1024), 1)
```

Comment: why is this a negative 1?  Please explain yourself negative rater so we understand why you did this.  Seems logical to me to just cast it like he did.

Comment: I disagree with down vote since the answer is correct if you oversee the easy-to-make mistake. But you did need to put the `new FileInfo(strFilePath).Length / 1024` in parenthesis to make it work.

Comment: The problem is that the divisions will still be integer division which will truncate, so rounding is pointless even if you cast to a double.